# How to use "msgpack" non-intrusively in c++?

Tags: c++, serialization, macros, msgpack, intrusive-containers

I'm using "msgpack" to serialize my messages.
There is a customized type that was defined in a 3rd party lib's header, I can **NOT** modify the include file, i.e. I should **NOT** add a `MSGPACK_DEFINE` into the declare of this class.

But I know that it is a int32_t indeed, and it also offers a getter method named `as<int32_t>();` like the following:

```
class GlobalCustomizedType_t {
    template <typename T>
    T as() const { return static_cast<T>( _data ); };
protected:
    int32_t _data;
};
```

Now I need to serialize my message struct that has a member of type GlobalCustomizedType_t with `msgpack`. Obviously I can't directly add a macro into my message struct, like this:

```
struct MyMessage_t {
    GlobalCustomizedType_t _glob;

    MSGPACK_DEFINE( _glob );
};
```

I have tried it like this:

```
struct MyMessage_t {
    GlobalCustomizedType_t _glob;

    MSGPACK_DEFINE( _glob.as<int32_t> );
};
```

But it still can't work.

Would anyone please to help me?
thx!

Comment: Have you checked [non-intrusive approach](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_adaptor#non-intrusive-approach) docs? (there is an example there)